# Kriging method to use for rainfall?

Tags: interpolation, kriging, precipitation

I am working on an rainfall analysis and I have to interpolate some datas with kriging method.

Is co-kriging suitable for the rainfall analysis?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to include proof of basic research effort and - if applicable - code so far. Questions requesting code or instructions to copy&paste are generally not well received.

Comment: Actually, I researched and I found kriging is best for me.However, which method of kriging I should use is little confusing

Answer (score 5):

For reliable methods, I would do a [**literature review**](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=rainfall+interpolation) to find the best option given your time, resources and questions you are trying to accomplish.

- [This one, so far, is popping out](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~kclarke/Geography232/Goovaerts_2000.pdf)

Comment: intresting paper. After quick look at the data table, I noticed a low correlation between the rainfall and the elevation, especially for the summer months. My initial thought would be that there is some kind of noise in the initial dataset. Can that be the case?

Comment: I'd say summer has less correlation due to local precipitation from convective cells, like thunder storms, which are less related to elevation.

Answer (score 3):

Co kringing needs another variable (the covariable), example - for rainfall, it could be the elevation. 
The best one to start its ordinary kriging.

Comment: Ordinary kriging is known to be bad for rainfall because rainfall is controlled strongly by topography and other factors.  Co-kriging is one attractive option because those other factors can be brought into the analysis.  Thus I have to disagree with this answer, which in other applications might otherwise be good advice.