# Weather data interpolation?

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, interpolation, weather

I'm trying to carry out weather conditions interpolations. I have information of 92 weather stations for 800,000 km2. As you can imagine the extension of land is huge and I need some kind or weather models to predict wind velocity and direction and solar irradiation for points in between the stations via interpolations. This means if I have a weather station in A and another one in C, I can know what is happening in B with weather interpolation models.

Do you know if QGIS does something alike? (maybe there is a plugin to download?) Are you familiar with any models that could help me out?

Comment: What data is your 92 Weather Stations generating?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mapperz, they generate: wind velocity, gust velocity, wind direction, gust direction, air temperature, relative humidity, pressure and solar radiation.

Comment: This is not free but worth looking into http://www.wxsim.com/  I don't think there is a plugin for qgis for weather modelling.

Comment: Your interpolation can be as simply as IDW or Kriging spatial interpolation or it can be very complex where you use intricate weather models that count for relationships between wind and temperature, temperature and humidity, pressure and wind etc. and you also consider the temporal factor. For the first case you can do it with QGIS but for the second you need special weather models and I don't think QGIS can do that.

Comment: If you *have* a set of stations and want to generate data in between, do you refer to interpolation (i.e. prediction in a geostatistical sense)? Or do you want to predict future data, i.e. forecasting? This is not clear from the question.

Comment: markusN, is to predict in a geostatistical sense, not forecast.

Comment: [windninja](windninja.firemodels.org) may be useful.  It simulates the affect that terrain has on wind.  It' s usually used for fire behavior modeling.  It's free.

Comment: In which part of the world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kriging method to use for rainfall?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66679/kriging-method-to-use-for-rainfall)